# fundamental type initialization C++

Tags: c++, initialization

When creating a variable of fundamental type such as :

```
double *aPtr = new double;
```

*(aPtr) will not be initialized.

Is there a way to make it initialized to a specific value (not necessarily 0), e.g. -1 ?

Is creating a new class the only way?

Comment: "...*(aPtr) will be initialized to 0." In most cases, it won't be initialized to anything.

Comment: My bad juanchopanza you are correct. 
Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - just do

```
double *aPtr = new double(-1);
```

*Here -1 is the example value from the post*